# Render a lot of spheres with different theta length with THREE.js

Tags: javascript, optimization, three.js

I am using

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 32, 16, 0, 2*Math.PI, 0, x);
```

with `x < 2*PI` to create a part of a sphere looking like that :

[image: an example of the geometry I want]

The thing is I need to have tens of thousands of those, all with the same center and radius but with different rotations and different and very small x values.

I have done research about instancing but can't find a way to use it the way I want to. Any suggestions ?

Comment: InstancedMesh is an option. Add an `InstancedBufferAttribute` to a sphere geometry for `phi` angle per instance and process this value in vertex shader, using `.onBeforeCompile()`.

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks I'll explore this idea ! I don't see what you mean by "process this value in vertex shader" though. Could you elaborate on how to process the value in vertex shader please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an additional `InstancedBufferAttribute` to pass `phi` angles per instance in `InstancedMesh`, and process those values in vertex shader to form the parts you want, using `.onBeforeCompile()` method.

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 5000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

let control = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

const MAX_COUNT = 10000;
let g = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 20, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, Math.PI * 0.25, Math.PI * 0.5);
let m = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  onBeforeCompile: shader => {
    shader.vertexShader = `
      attribute float instPhi;
      
      // straight from the docs on Vector3.setFromSphericalCoords
      vec3 setFromSphericalCoords( float radius, float phi, float theta ) {

        float sinPhiRadius = sin( phi ) * radius;

        float x = sinPhiRadius * sin( theta );
        float y = cos( phi ) * radius;
        float z = sinPhiRadius * cos( theta );

        return vec3(x, y, z);

      }
      
      ${shader.vertexShader}
    `.replace(
      `#include <beginnormal_vertex>`,
      `#include <beginnormal_vertex>
        
        vec3 sphPos = setFromSphericalCoords(1., instPhi * (1. - uv.y), PI * 2. * uv.x); // compute position
        objectNormal = normalize(sphPos); // normal is just a normalized vector of the computed position
        
     `).replace(
      `#include <begin_vertex>`,
       `#include <begin_vertex>
        transformed = sphPos; // set computed position
       `
     );
    //console.log(shader.vertexShader);
  }
});
let im = new THREE.InstancedMesh(g, m, MAX_COUNT);
scene.add(im);

let v3 = new THREE.Vector3();
let c = new THREE.Color();
let instPhi = []; // data for Phi values
let objMats = new Array(MAX_COUNT).fill().map((o, omIdx) => {
  let om = new THREE.Object3D();
  om.position.random().subScalar(0.5).multiplyScalar(100);
  om.rotation.setFromVector3(v3.random().multiplyScalar(Math.PI));
  om.updateMatrix();
  im.setMatrixAt(omIdx, om.matrix);
  im.setColorAt(omIdx, c.set(Math.random() * 0xffffff))
  instPhi.push((Math.random() * 0.4 + 0.1) * Math.PI);
  return om;
});
g.setAttribute("instPhi", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(instPhi), 1));

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

</script>
```

PS May be turned into the using of `InstancedBufferGeometry`. Creativity is up to you :)

Comment: This is great ! Any chance there are a few optimizations to be made, or am I asking too much ahah ?

Comment: @Paul What optimizations? O_o

Comment: that is an amazing piece of code ahah don't get me wrong ! But if I could make it work with like a million spheres that would be just perfect !! Right now I can "only" do around 100K, so I was wondering if there was anything I could do to make it run faster.